# Let $S,L\subset V$, both finite. If $\textrm{span}(S)=V$ and $L$ is LI, $|S| \geq |L|$. (Artin's proof and alternative proof.)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-independence

Proposition (3.16) of Artin's Algebra book (1st edition, page 92) claims that the order of a subset $L$ of a vector space $V$, which contains only linearly independent (LI) vectors can't be greater than the order of another subset $S$ that spans $V$.

The first part of my question is about the proof himself writes, and the second part is about a proof that I attempted to get.

**Part 1: Artin's proof**

Artin reduces the task of finding a dependence relation of the vectors in $L$ by finding out when the system of equations

$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_ja_{ij}v_i =0$, where $\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_ja_{ij}$ are the coefficients. In matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \vert & \vert&   & \vert\\ v_1   & v_2  &...& v_m\\ \vert & \vert&   &\vert\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sum_{j=1}^{n}c_ja_{1j} \\ \sum_{j=1}^{n}c_ja_{2j}\\ \vdots \\\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_ja_{mj}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

He states that this is a system of $m$ unknowns and $n$ equations, where $n$ is the order of $L$.

What I cannot understand is why this system has $n$ equations. What I can see, in not very abstract terms, is that the number of equations is the length of the vectors $v_i$ (i.e. the dimension of $V$).

**Part 2: Alternative proof**

Let $m$ be the order of $S$, so it contains $m$ vectors. Among these $m$ vectors, only a number $k\leq m$ will be LI.

By virtue of proposition (3.10) in the same book, the span generated by that subset of $k$ LI vectors (call it $\tilde{S}$) is equal to the span generated by the whole set $S$, namely the whole vector space $V$.

This means that any vector in $L\subset V$, is also in $\textrm{span}(\tilde{S})$,so it can be expressed as a linear combination of these $k$ independent vectors. No more than $k$ LI vectors can be obtained by combining $k$ LI vectors: can get the same set of $k$ vectors and then linear combinations of them. Then the order of $L$ can be at most the number of LI vectors in $S$, and thus no greater than the order of $S$ itself.

If possible I'd like to ask for a clarification of the last statement in the proof of part 1, and for a check of part 2 being correct.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer your first question with certainty, without knowing more about the proof. How are the (vectors?) $v_i$ constructed? What about the (scalars?) $c_{ij}$ and $a_j$? They must relate somehow to $L$ and $S$, but it's not clear how.

Comment: You should say this is in Artin *1st edition*.  What is really going on is write each linearly independent $\mathbf l_j$ in terms of spanning vectors and collect in matrix form : $\mathbf SA =\mathbf L$. By (2.17) from chapter 1, $A$ is tall and skinny (rows $\geq$ cols) since for all $\mathbf x \neq \mathbf 0$ we know $\mathbf L\mathbf x \neq \mathbf 0$ by linear independence thus $A\mathbf x \neq \mathbf 0$ for all $\mathbf x\neq \mathbf 0$ (by associativity).  But $A$ has $n$ columns and and $m$ rows hence $m\geq n$.

Comment: @user8675309 thank you, your explanation is clear and now I can relate it to Artin's. Could you comment on part 2 of the question? If you post that as an answer together with a critique of my potential proof I could vote for it.

Comment: @TheoBendit I added the page in the mentioned book too, do you have access to it? Otherwise I could edit in more details that I omitted from the reference.

Comment: @abcd I don't have access to it. It sounds like user8675309 cleared up any confusion on interpreting the proof as written, so it's probably not really necessary to add extra detail. As I understand your proof, you have a L.I. set $L$ and spanning set $S$, then reduce $S$ to a L.I. set $\tilde{S}$ with the same span. Then, vectors in $L$ are linear combinations of $\tilde{S}$. How can you conclude that $|L| \le |\tilde{S}|$? Is there a particular result from Artin's book that states this?

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for responding, I have not supported that conclusion with any other result from Artin's book, but could you ever get more than $k$ LI vectors by forming linear combinations of $k$ LI vectors? Isn't this a fact by definition? This is how I'm concluding $|L|\leq|\tilde{S}|$ but please correct if I'm wrong. The only result I used from Artin (Proposition 3.10) is that removing linearly dependent vectors from a set does not change its span.

Comment: @abcd I did see that you supported the conclusion that you can reduce a set to a linearly independent set with the same span (which is good). The problem I have is with saying you can get at most $k$ linearly independent vectors from the span of $k$ linearly independent vectors. While this is definitely true, I would not say that this is true "by definition". Linear independence is usually defined in terms of $0$ being a unique linear combination of the vectors. How do you know there isn't a creative way of taking $k+1$ linear combinations of these vectors so that the result is LI?